# Choose a picture from the gallery only, not other application like Photos App

Tags: android, image, gallery

I am trying to pick an image from the Android Gallery only, not other applications like Photos, file manager etc

I need a solution to open the Gallery App directly, or is it possible to use the Photos Application to pick image?

1) Choose from gallery

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

2)   onActivityResult result code

```
try {
    // bimatp factory
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger images
    options.inSampleSize = 2;
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),options);

    descimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, new FileOutputStream(new File(fileUri.getPath())));

    photostatus = 1;
    pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    txtbrowser.setEnabled(false);
    new upload().execute();

} catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that [Gallery no longer exists](http://www.androidcentral.com/where-did-gallery-go-after-lollipop-update) on some devices running Lollipop. The photos app is the replacement and it should have no problems handling the intent to select an image. `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is usually [recommended for selecting images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765265/difference-between-intent-action-get-content-and-intent-action-pick/17765424#17765424), such as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, ID);
```

Opening the gallery on devices that do have it installed is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066013/launching-gallery-in-android-phones). Basically every different vendor may ship a different gallery app.

It is possible to launch a specific activity for an implicit intent (such as selecting an image) without showing the chooser dialog by using the [PackageManager.queryIntentActivities()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) API to iterate all the available packages on the users device so you can explicitly launch the one you require.

Answer (score 0):

This intent allows you to pick the image from the default gallery.

```
 // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to  select a file
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

For receiving the selected image in `onActivityResult()`

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }
```

i got the solution from [here](https://github.com/hanscappelle/SO-2169649)