# Select Image only from Gallery android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I am using the following code to open Gallery for image selection

```
private void galleryIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.select_file)), SELECT_FILE);
```

All is working fine but for the first time it gives a popup with two options to select:

[image]

**Can I make my app such that it always open Gallery Directly without any such popup?**

Thanks

Comment: startActivityForResult(Intent);

Comment: Why do you think that your users want to use whatever you think "Gallery" is? If the users have another activity that supports picking an image from the `MediaStore`, let them use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every gallery app has its own package name which can differ from device to device. To do what you intend, you must know the package name of the gallery app. Some device may not even have a default gallery app.

What you have done is the right way to go and the user can decide to set the gallery app as the default app. Unless for very important or specific reason, it is more reasonable to give the user the choice.

Look at [Launching Gallery in android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066013/launching-gallery-in-android-phones)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 
    PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Comment: This will open the File Explorer of Android

Comment: it works for me and this will open only images of your device each n every image...

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"))               
     startActivity(intent);
```

or else u can try this...

```
         Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
         startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android 10 an intent with ACTION_PICK opens gallery

```
Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_PICK
    type = "image/*"
}
```

when the intent with ACTION_GET_CONTENT opens file chooser

```
Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    type = "image/*"
}
```